# Find E(X) & E(X^2) given that the probability mass function of the variable X is given as follows:

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, random-variables

This is my question:

[image: My question.]

This is my attempt:

[image: my attempt.]

Hi, I have tried to solve this problem but I cannot figure it out. Normally, when given a range for x in a function, it would be the Probability Density Function but this question gives a range for x in a Probability Mass Function. I'm not sure how to solve for E(X) and E(X^2) for a range because probability mass function suggests I use summations but then the range suggests I use integration. I attempted to use integration to solve the problem but my answers were wrong, can you help me out please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Is $X$ a continuous random variable?  A discrete one?  What is the set of possible values for $X$?

Comment: The question is not clear.  If $x$ is any real number in $(0,a]$ then the integral of $\frac kx$ diverges (assuming $k>0$.

Comment: question is very badly worded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess, $X$ can take on only the values from $1$ to $a$, as a discrete distribution has a pmf. Also it speaks of $P(X=x)$, which is infinitesimal for a continuous distribution.

So based on that, it says $P(X=1) = k, P(X=2) = k/2, ...$ up to $P(X=a) = k/a$.

From here, use $E[X] = \sum x p(x)$ and $E[X^2] = \sum x^2 p(x)$.